# When does Skitch use a transparent background?

Tags: screen-capture, skitch

I am using [Skitch Plus](http://skitch.com) to take screenshots of applications running on my Mac, and I have noticed it has an option to set the background.

[image: screenshot]

What I still have to understand is when that option is used. As it is evident from the screenshot, it is not used when I take a screenshot of part of the screen, and (from the following screenshot) when I take a screenshot of the full screen.

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody know when the transparent background is ever used?
I am using the Mac OS X Lion; is the option not working in this Mac OS X, but working for previous versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Skitch, but from the context (note it is indented under a checkbox) I think the option would apply to screenshots taken of **whole windows**.

Comment: I was used to a different application, which made a distinction between "cross hair screenshot," "window screenshot," and "fullscreen screenshot." I guess that is why I have never noticed I could take a window screenshot by clicking on it; that then explains why I have never understood that option, or noticed it was grouped with other options.

Comment: Ah. I was wondering myself why the listing of keyboard shortcuts didn't have one for windows.